# Artifactories integration with Bazel

Tags: build, artifactory, bazel

I am currently trying to build a project with source in a git repository and some dependencies in an artifactory. I need to first download all the sources and binaries from the repo and artifactory to my local workspace.

I could not find any information regarding artifactory integration with bazel. I can see that this feature has been requested https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15428?jql=labels%20%3D%20bazel.
Is anyone aware of any build tools that can first download resources and then build them?
I need both git and artifactory support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Bazel documentation for Java](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#external-packages), you can define external dependencies resolved to Maven with rule `maven_jar`.

As Artifactory supports Maven, you can set up your dependencies in a Maven repository, and retrieve artifacts from there with your Bazel build script.

On the other side of the build, publication seems to be [a work-in-progress](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1372) and [on the roadmap](https://bazel.build/roadmap.html) for Bazel builds.

Comment: How do folks handle authentication to a private Artifactory repository using bazel.  This is a blocker for us.

Answer (score 2):

You can also attempt to write the artifactory rules in Skylark: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html

Answer (score 2):

## Remote build cache

Bazel supports any HTTP 1.1 server with PUT and GET methods as http cache. Simple HTTP Auth is also supported. This means using Artifactory as a remote build cache is straightforward.

1. Create a new Generic repository in Artifactory.

Now run bazel as

```
bazel test \
   --remote_http_cache=https://user:password@[...].com:8081/artifactory/bazel/ \
   test //...
```

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html for the relevant Bazel doc.